# RSS feed question

Tags: rss

Do I really need all those xmlns links in my RSS code?

what does the following code mean?

```
<rss version="2.0"
xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
>
```

Answer (score 6):

The `xmlns` properties define [XML namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace).

For instance, `xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` defines the namespace `atom` to be the `URI` http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom.

Then, when you create a `<atom:link>` element, you can see it as having the URI http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom/link, which the parser will know is a link, as defined in the Atom specification.

Note, the parser cannot go by the name of the namespace, as you just as easily could have used `xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"`, which would make `<a:link>` the Atom link tag.